# What is the difference between hybrid application and a phone-gap cardova application?

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

If I need to explain my self whats the difference between a hybrid app and a application built using phonegap, how I am going to explain ?

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap is an implementation of a hybrid approach. It is best to consider it a "hybrid framework". Another version of a hybrid application could be build mainly native and then use webviews (UIWebView on iOS, WebView on Android) for certain cross-platform pages. There are still many other frameworks and designs for "hybrid".

Generally the more important comparison is web vs. native vs. hybrid.

These should help you as well:

http://www.asyncdev.net/2012/10/phonegap-a-misunderstood-hybrid-framework/

http://www.icenium.com/blog/icenium-team-blog/2012/06/14/what-is-a-hybrid-mobile-app-

Answer (score 1):

**Phonegap**

*PhoneGap is basically a Hybrid Application.*

**What is PhoneGap Trying To Accomplish?**

The purpose of PhoneGap is to allow HTML-based web applications to be deployed and installed as native applications. PhoneGap web applications are wrapped in a native application shell, and can be installed via the native app stores for multiple platforms. Additionally, PhoneGap strives to provide a common native API set which is typically unavailable to web applications, such as basic camera access, device contacts, and sensors not already exposed in the browser.

To run a PhoneGap application on a native emulator/simulator, developers will generate a project for each of the native platforms they wish to support, configure that project’s “web root” directory in Xcode, Eclipse, or whatever native toolchain is needed, and then run the project using that tool.

**Strengths of the PhoneGap Approach**

Any native platform that supports a web view or web runtime can be a PhoneGap platform. Anyone who can write HTML, CSS, and even a small bit of JavaScript can wrap up a web page in a native app and distribute it as such. The barrier to entry in using PhoneGap to package web pages as native apps is extremely low.

**Weaknesses of the PhoneGap Approach**

The quality of the user interface in a PhoneGap application will vary based on the quality of the web view and rendering engine on the platform. The Webkit-based rendering engine on iOS is strong, and provides the best performance. The Android web view is functional, but has some notable limitations.

PhoneGap also cannot be extended with native user interface. The end developer’s application its self lives inside a web view, and user interface is rendered in HTML.

Check this link for more Info : [Phonegap Tutorial](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap is environment where we can implement hybrid application. You can say Phonegap is implementation tool. Hybrid App which run on cross platform. Hybrid app create through CSS,javascript,html which run on multiple plateform. A hybrid application (hybrid app) is one that combines elements of both native and Web applications.

More Details you can see :

[https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Native,_HTML5,_or_Hybrid:_Understanding_Your_Mobile_Application_Development_Options](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Native,_HTML5,_or_Hybrid%3a_Understanding_Your_Mobile_Application_Development_Options)

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_overview_index.md.html#Overview

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/in/events/softwareuniverse/resources/Native_web_or_hybrid_mobile-app_development.pdf