# Converting ios project to android using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, ios7, xcode5

I have created an ios app using Xcode .Now I have to make it run on android also.So I downloaded phonegap 2.0 and create an xcode project using commandLine`(./create ~/Desktop/newfolder com.companyname.projectname projectname)`.After that I added all the required classes and storyboard file of allready created ios project to this new one(created by using Phonegap utilities).

And now I can run this project.What I want to know is ,

1. Is this the correct way to make my ios app cross platform?
2. Is there any rule that only app created using CSS html5 and
   javascript can be made crossplatform using Phonegap?

If my steps are wrong do I need to create the same project using CSS html5 and javascript again for making it cross platform.

Comment: Check the functionalities of Phonegap here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24645953/1785412

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve such functionality using PhoneGap, here is the wikipage for [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap)
It says that it enables software programmers to build applications for mobile devices using JavaScript, HTML5, and CSS.
PhoneGap has different builds for different architectures, so once you've written your entire app using HTML5, CSS and JavaScript you can make build for every different platform available.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to port iOS project into android it is not possible but if you want to port a HTML5 application you can do it using PhoneGap.

Create a PhoneGap project for android using command-line interface. Have a look at the [Cordova Command-Line Interface](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface). 
Add the CSS, Javascript, HTML, image files inside respective folders. Also, add plugins required for the application using the command-line interface.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

First off the bat, if you're looking to port an existing Objective-C based iOS project then **it is not possible** to do so with PhoneGap.

PhoneGap or Apache Cordova as it is known now is not the *only* framework that can be used to write cross platform apps. I personally think it is one of the more well supported ones (*being an open platform*) and yes it is based on familiar web technologies i.e. HTML + CSS + Javascript and you **are** limited to using only this combination but then web frameworks are good enough for most development requirements these days. [This is a good place to start](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/index.html) off with Cordova development.

Cordova 3.x.x onward has matured well as a framework and post creation of a project one can *add* platforms using the command line interface (CLI). This is the common structure of a Cordova project :

```
/hooks /merges /platforms /plugins /www config.xml
```

The /www folder contains the web app that you're developing, typically :

```
/img /css /js index.html
```

The /platforms folder contains the projects for the various platforms that you've requested, typically :

```
/android /ios
```

It is these folders that contain the projects that need to be imported by the IDE that you're using. Say, for Android, import the contents of the *android* folder as an *Existing Android Code Into WorkSpace* and build it normally as an Android project. That is all.

Nonetheless, it has many limitations like the lack of support for in app billing, 3D graphics etc. I would like to suggest that you consider making native apps for all platforms you intend to support.